# Force Nosetests to Use Python 2.7 instead of 3.4

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, web.py, nosetests

I've been learning Python using version 3.4. I recently started learning Web.py so have been using Python 2.7 for that, since web.py not supported in Python 3.4.  I have nose 1.3.4 module installed for both Python 3.4 and 2.7.  I need to run the nosetests command on some Python code written in 2.7 that uses the Web.py module.  However, when I type nosetests command it automatically uses Python 3.4, so is throwing an error as unable to import the Web.py module in my Python code.  Is there a way to force nosetests to use Python 2.7?  Macbook Pro running OS X Yosemite.

Comment: Well, it is most likely calling /usr/bin/python which is pointing to 3.4, so just change the link to point at 2.7.

Comment: sorry for sounding dumb but I'm relatively new to programing.  Can you specify what you mean.  How do I change the link?

Comment: I could but I won't! Instead I will point you to read up about symlinks, and how to switch python versions on OS X somewhere in depths of google.

Comment: Puciek's guidance is good, but you probably don't want to change your global python version every time you switch projects. Instead, use a separate [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/virtualenv.html) for each project.

Comment: I guessed that a virtualenv is the correct approach.  But, reverting to my original question, is there a terminal command to to force it to run the nosetests in Python 2.7, instead of 3.4?

Comment: Try `python2.7 -m nose` instead of running `nosetests`.

Comment: That worked! Thank you!  Can you explain how that works?  What does the -m do?

Comment: Was hoping to use this same mechanism to do a 2.6 sanity check since I have a dev 2.7 but a jenkin 2.6 right now. No luck though; `/usr/bin/python2.6: nose is a package and cannot be directly executed`

Answer (score 6):

As @dano suggeted in his comment:

Try `python2.7 -m nose` instead of running `nosetests`.