# Force nose2 to use Python 2.7 instead of Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-2.7, nose2

Similar to [Force Nosetests to Use Python 2.7 instead of 3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26579670/force-nosetests-to-use-python-2-7-instead-of-3-4), I've written some unit tests in Python 2 which I'd like to run in Python 2. However, by default my installation of `nose2` seems to try to run Python 3.

For example, if I try to run `unittest_controller.py` I get output ending with

```
Ran 4 tests in 1.552s

OK
```

whereas if I use the command `nose2` from the same directory, I get

```
ImportError: No module named 'StringIO'


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=2)
```

because `StringIO` is no longer a module in Python 3. How can I run the tests using Python 2?

Comment: As an alternative, it might be simpler to just run `2to3` on your Python 2 files.

Comment: [Eli Sadoff](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5021321/eli-sadoff), that's what I did in the end.