# How to test Python 2 code using nose2

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose2

I've asked this question before ([Force nose2 to use Python 2.7 instead of Python 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40406122/force-nose2-to-use-python-2-7-instead-of-python-3-5)) but didn't get an answer, and thought I might give it another try. I'm trying to run tests using the command

```
nose2
```

but I'm getting an error that ends with

```
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

It seems like [nose2](https://github.com/nose-devs/nose2) assumes that the code is in Python 3, whereas in this case it is in Python 2. Is there any way to make `nose2` work on Python 2 code? (For example by changing its configuration)?

Comment: According to [this](http://nose2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/differences.html) document nose2 should support Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.2 and above. Are you sure your using python2 interpreter? There is lot of [differences](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_python_2_3_key_diff.html) between python2 and python3. Syntax error you mentioned suggests that you try run python2 code with python3 interpreter.

Comment: Following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079036/detect-python-version-at-runtime, I checked my Python version using a script containing `print(sys.version_info[0])`, and it returns `2`.

Comment: Incidentally, another testing program which worked 'as is' is [pytest](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/). Its test discovery methods are slightly different (for example, I had to rename the test scripts to start with `test_` or end with `_test`), but I find the terminal output more user-friendly than `nose2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nose2 takes whatever python is configured in the shebang line.

To test a python2 project use (executable and path might differ on your machine):

```
python2.7 /usr/local/bin/nose2
```

verified with this example:

**test.py**:

```
def test_the_program():
    print "foo"
```

**with python3**:

```
$ python3 /usr/local/bin/nose2
======================================================================
ERROR: test (nose2.loader.ModuleImportFailure)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: test
    (...)
    print "hans"
               ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

**with python2.7**:

```
$ python2.7 /usr/local/bin/nose2
foo
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```